# Is Covariance Matrix analogous to Jacobian Matrix?

Tags: probability, optimization, covariance-matrix, jacobian

In probability theory covariance matrix denote how each variable relates to other in a pairwise manner. So 1 would mean they are identical and 0 would mean they are independent and are not related. Is this concept similar to Jacobian matrix where such relation between multiple variables are denoted by partial derivative?

Comment: Because covariance matrices represent *quadratic forms* (which is why they are always symmetric and positive semi-definite) and Jacobians represent arbitrary *linear transformations,* about the only thing they have in common is that they are square matrices.  Your question sounds like you are asking whether apples and squid are similar.  They are in the sense that they are derived from living things, but there's little to recommend the comparison.

Comment: allright makes sense! +1 for creative analogy

Comment: In general, whuber is right. But there are actually some similarities. And in some cases, the covariance matrix *is* the jacobian matrix -- e.g. when a variable transformation is performed; to be more precise, it would need to be a linear transformation, otherwise it's only an approximation. In general it helps to think of the Jacobian simply as the derivative in spaces with dimension larger one. But I'd also be careful to associate covariance with "how a variable relates to another"; it's just the expectation value of the product.

Comment: @cherub is there any concrete example you would like to share where covariance matrix is the jacabian matrix. My initial motivation of seeking similarities between the two were due to taking point-wise partial derivative in Jacobian matrix where each element of the matrix quantify how one varies when other being kept constant. or relative increment. Can this notion be related to an equivalent element of covariance matrix where this relative increment is quantified as expectation value of the product of the corresponding variables?

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER I'm sorry, I don't really understand what your question is. There are formal similarities between Covariance matrices and Jacobians, as whuber mentioned. But they are still entirely different things. I was just trying to state that under certain circumstances a particular Jacobian can be the Covariance matrix. In that particular case, this makes sense; you can express the variation of one variable exactly by a particular formula, which happens to be the derivative. But in general this is not true. Covariance matrices are generally not transformation matrices; but Jacobians are.

Comment: @cherub yes whuber made good analogy that they both are similar as they are square matrices.  I wanted to know that under what circumstances a Jacobian can be a covariance matrix as you stated. I think you answered that in this comment that in circumstances where we variation of one variable can be expressed by a formula that happens to be a derivative. I am just curious if there is a concrete example for when the variation of one variable can be expressed by a particular formula in a derivative form so covariance matrix is indeed jacobian matrix.

Comment: @cherub much of what you write is confusing.  In particular, any covariance matrix can be considered a linear transformation--that's standard, but in a statistical application it is important to describe *what* it might be transforming.  A Jacobian cannot possibly be a covariance matrix unless it is square, symmetric, and positive-semidefinite, which in more than one dimension would be a rare circumstance, and even then it's unclear what it would be the covariance of.

Comment: @whuber: I'm sorry that I added to the confusion. Yes, it is a special circumstance that the Jacobian is square. When I'm teaching about coordinate transformations (I'm a physicist) this actually comes up frequently. In most cases the transformation isn't linear (e.g. cartesian to spherical), so it's just the first order approximation. But sometimes (e.g. simple translations or scaling -- linear), it is true. I tried to add a little practical info, but didn't intend to confuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather say that the covariance matrix is similar to the Hessian matrix  .. Furthermore, the Hessian tends to be proportional to the precision matrix (which is the inverse of the covarinace matrix). The intuition behind is that the higher the curvature in a given direction is, the lower the auto-covariance (the variance) in that same direction will be.

Comment: Hi, could you please provide more details in the answer. In terms of how parwise relation in Jacobian matrix conveys something. Also how is covariance matrix similar to Hessian matrix where single element is partial second derivative?

Comment: Assuming a linear relationship between Y and X in the form $Y=aX+b$, the first derivative (Jacobian) will be a constant equal to the regression coefficient $a$ which is proportional to $Cov(Y,X)$ , whereas the second derivative (Hessian) will be 0. In general, pairwise, a null Hessian coefficient means there is a collinearity or a correlation between variables, the degree of intensity of this correlation is conveyed by the Jacobian coefficient. But, the Jacobian coefficient must be constant, otherwise the relationship would be of a higher order than a simple collinearity.

Comment: alright. this is the worked example I was looking for. Also why is it that "higher the curvature in a given direction is, the lower the auto-covariance (the variance) in that same direction will be"?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the direction of $x$ axis in the figure below. At a fixed $y$ ($y = 15$ in the example) the sample of points $x_i$ drawn from the blue plot has a higher variance than the red sample. However, in the same direction $x$, the red plot has a higher curvature $.6$ compared to the blue one $.2$.
[image]

Comment: Could you explain how any of these plots determine how to draw samples??

Comment: @whuber could this be that he meant to show normal distribution, so blue would have higher variance and red with lower variance and the in the x-axis line the red/blue points are the draws? I am curious to see how this particular example can be worked out to show how plots determine the sample draws.

Comment: @metron I don't see anything resembling a Normal distribution in this plot.

Comment: We can just draw a uniform sample from the interval $[0,15]$ on the $y$  $axis$, then map each sample to its projection on the $x$  $axis$  via one of the plots. Using the same original uniform sample, we get the visualized blue samples when the projection occurs via the blue plot and the red ones when it occurs via the red plot.

Comment: @whuber, I believe the explanation using uniform sample from the y-axis and checking its projection on x-axis given the three plots makes sense, right?

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER Nothing about that "explanation" makes much sense, beginning with the fact that the y-axis does *not* map to the x-axis (there's no objective way to determine the sign of the result) and the red and blue smears on the x-axis clearly do not correspond, even qualitatively, with the result of such an approach.

Comment: @whuber I got your point. I thought I was beginning to understand the notion of curvature with respect to variance.

Comment: @whuber There was a little imprecision in the first figure, it is fixed now. I hope it makes more sense. I gave a geometric interpretation but we could find a proper analytical formulation that is not necessary to grasp the main idea.

Comment: Thanks -- the consistency helps us understand the idea.  It looks like you may be trying to establish a connection based on a "delta method" type of analysis, but specifically how isn't completely clear.